# What is the correct way to create Mock input interface in Web-Api functional test?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, testing, unit-tests

I've already write successfully a Web-Api unit test for a Custom API. But I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically create a Mock for input data for the API?

For example, AccountManagement have:

```
 /**
     * Create customer account. Perform necessary business operations like sending email.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
     * @param string $password
     * @param string $redirectUrl
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function createAccount(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer,
        $password = null,
        $redirectUrl = ''
    );
```

There a way to create a Mock for the CustomerInterface using PHPUnit?